# How to access to assets when the project root is different directory with PhpStorm?

Tags: php, html, css, phpstorm

I'm developing on local environment with PhpStorm. The directories is like this.

```
 project
 └── public
     ├── css
     │   └── style.css
     └── index.html
```

The source code of html contains relative path like `/css/style.css`.
When I open index.html using browser preview with PhpStorm, the path to css is to `http://localhost:<port>/css/style.css` although it should be to `http://localhost:<port>/project/public/css/style.css`.

I tried to set the resource root to public directory but the problem could not be resolved.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/content-root.html

Comment: Yes, marking `public` as a Resource Root is needed here. What web server do you use to serve the website: PhpStorm's simple build in web server or a proper Apache/nginx/IIS/etc? PhpStorm's one should actually work (as per multiple dev comments that I have seen in the past). In any case: I suggest to use proper web server as it's more close to the way how it will be served in production.

Comment: @LazyOne
Thanks for your reply. I use PhpStorm's built-in web server.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-built-in-web-server.html

Comment: I don't get it. PhpStorm seems to be doing the right thing. `public` is a widespread naming convention stating that everything underneath is not visible through the web server. If you want to publish your entire codebase just move `index.html` and stuff to top level folder.

Comment: @N.Fujii I suggest installing some XAMPP/WAMP/MAMP all-in-one package or whatever else you prefer (if you do not want to install just a webserver separately) so you have a proper web server. Then configure it to serve your website -- it is better than built-in in many ways (as it requires to use URLs like `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/the-rest/of/url` where `PROJECT_NAME` part MUST be present). With proper webserver you configure your website as you wish, especially if you use fake/local domain name (via local `hosts` file)

Comment: @N.Fujii Once you can use your web site in a browser, just define Deployment entry in PhpStorm (can be just "in-place" type, so no file copying will be done; + specify the website URL there) and mark it as Default for this project. Now PhpStorm will use that URL when you use "Open in Browser" or alike. When no default deployment is provided then URL is build as if built-in web server is used.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for your reply. I have reasons that I can't change the directory structure...

Comment: @LazyOne I made another choice and resolved. I installed apache instead of PhpStorm's built-in server. Thanks for your a lot of advices.